# jQuery autocomplete: use classes

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, mysqli

I am trying to call the autocomplete function on all textboxes with class='matricula' so that when they lose focus, the boxes to their right will be populated with data coming from the same record (the query that I use to do this is found in the php files buscaralumno.php and alumno.php).
The thing is, the way it is right now when the cursor leaves the first textbox in the first row, it populates ALL the remaining textboxes - not only the first row.
So the bottom line would be: when I enter at least 2 letters in the first textbox in each row, a list suggesting possible values should pop up (which is what it does right now) and when I press the tab key to change focus to the next textbox, the remaining textboxes should be populated with the values of the remaining fields. In other words, one row of textboxes corresponds to a record from the database.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jqueryui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".matricula" ).autocomplete({
         source: "buscaralumno.php",
         position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right top", collision: "flip" },
         messages: { noResults: '', results: '' },
         minLength: 2
     });

     $(".matricula").focusout(function(){
         $.ajax({
             url:'alumno.php',
             type:'POST',
             dataType:'json',
             data:{ matricula:$('.matricula').val()}
         }).done(function(respuesta){
             $(".nombre").val(respuesta.nombre);
             $(".paterno").val(respuesta.paterno);
             $(".materno").val(respuesta.materno);
         });
     });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <form>
    <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
    <input type="text" class="matricula" name="matricula" value=""/>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="nombre" name="nombre" value=""/>
    <label for="paterno">Paterno:</label>
    <input type="text" class="paterno" name="paterno" value=""/>
    <label for="materno">Materno:</label>
    <input type="text" class="materno" name="materno" value=""/><br>
    <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
    <input type="text" class="matricula" name="matricula" value=""/>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="nombre" name="nombre" value=""/>
    <label for="paterno">Paterno:</label>
    <input type="text" class="paterno" name="paterno" value=""/>
    <label for="materno">Materno:</label>
    <input type="text" class="materno" name="materno" value=""/><br>
 </form>
```

Any hints will be more than appreciated. I apologize if this question is poorly phrased. I am fairly new to jQuery and English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".matricula").focusout(function(){
    var $row = $(this), inputs = $row.nextUntil('.matricula', 'input');
    $.ajax({
        url:'alumno.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{ matricula:$('.matricula').val()}
    }).done(function(respuesta){
        inputs.filter(".nombre").val(respuesta.nombre);
        inputs.filter(".paterno").val(respuesta.paterno);
        inputs.filter(".materno").val(respuesta.materno);
    });
});
```

Comment: That almost did the trick! :). Let me explain further. I have the following 2 records in the database: (id - matricula - nombre - paterno - materno) --> (1,'gacanepa','Gabriel','Canepa','Gonzalez'),(2,'gabanepa','Gerardo','Pineda','Martinez'). The autocomplete is set in the 'matricula' field. It works in all textboxes with class 'matricula', but only the first row is populated with the data from the first record in the database.